# Кнопка "Изменить тревогу"

Tags: предложение, локализация

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По сути, эта кнопа не изменяет тревогу, а отзывает её, не давая возможности её потом изменить. Может стоит тогда переименовать, чтобы не было путаницы, например, на "Отозвать тревогу"?

Comment: А если было поставлено несколько тревог?

Comment: @Qwertiy в смысле? На вопрос/ответ ведь можно ставить 1 тревогу, откуда несколько?

Comment: Можно несколько. Нельзя одновременно первые две - они одинаковые. Всегда можно добавить последнюю. Про другие комбинации не уверен, но вроде тоже можно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В оригинале там [`Retract Flag`](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/91489758?key=c437293b69e113542d49a2793b5fdf00). Так что выполнил перевод как:

> Отозвать тревогу

Надеюсь, все будут довольны.

Comment: Много лет играю в "мафию", там используется такой же термин, если кто-то хочет отозвать выставленную кандидатуру. Мне слух не режет в общем ;)